# Cross-Validation in R error with hcv function. How can I fix the error?

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis, cross-validation

### My code is as follows

```
 library(faraway)
 data(divusa)
 library(sm)

 hm<-hcv(divusa$year, divusa$divorce, display="Lines")
```

## Output

```
hcv: boundary of search area reached. 
Try readjusting hstart and hend. 
hstart:  0.994012 
hend  :  19.88024 

         h        cv
[1,]  0.994012  27.82906
[2,]  1.524941  38.89271
[3,]  2.339454  57.27233
[4,]  3.589020  86.72126
[5,]  5.506015 144.23398
[6,]  8.446928 255.30853
[7,] 12.958663 392.76460
[8,] 19.880241 491.59201
Error in hcv(divusa$year, divusa$divorce, display = "Lines") :
```

### Error message

Error in hcv(divusa$year, divusa$divorce, display = "Lines") :

Comment: Error message looks incomplete

Comment: I verified that the error message I am getting is what is written above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a full answer but just a hint of what your error is.

Actually, your error message comes at the beginning of the output of `hcv`:

> hcv: boundary of search area reached.
>
> Try readjusting hstart and hend.

Take a look to the paper reference on their help, *Bowman, A.W. and Azzalini, A. (1997). Applied Smoothing Techniques for Data Analysis: the Kernel Approach with S-Plus Illustrations*. You may download it in [this link](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl7a3ar47MAhVBvRQKHRFOB8YQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv006i07%2Fsm-doc_r.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFpexFJ9dCaSMoWvwit5zkSDcDlRQ&sig2=eH4Cmxq9nBTPnA142N79QA&bvm=bv.119408272,d.bGg).

In the paper, the authors take an example and find the same error message; it is an error of convergence, although the explanation is a bit dense, and I'm not sure it applies to your problem. Are you fitting the `divusa` data just as an exercise? There's also a book, I don't know if you are following it (I don't have it).

The answer to your question would be: you need to tune your parameters to make it work. But honestly I don't know how to do it (tried a few things with no luck).

Hope it helps in some way, good luck.